How can I write a macro to create the Match block for an Enum Dispatch?
I'm using EnumDispatch to store the possible Actions I want to take, and each Action is a struct I need to give arguments to.
#[enum_dispatch]
pub trait ActionRunner {
    fn run(&self);
}

#[enum_dispatch(ActionRunner)]
#[derive(Debug)]
enum ActionsEnum {
    MyAction,
    MyAction2,
}

let action: ActionsEnum = match my_output.action.name.as_str() {

        "MyAction" => {
            let foo: MyAction = serde_json::from_value(args).unwrap();
            foo.into()
        },
        "MyAction2" => {
            let foo: MyAction2 = serde_json::from_value(args).unwrap();
            foo.into()
        },

                
        _ => panic!("No found action"),
    };


I'm trying to avoid having to write that Match statement by writing a macro and I think I'm not far from getting it but I'm struggling to find out how I need to pass the arguments:
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! match_all_variants {
    ($input_str:expr, $action_args:ident, $enum_type:ident, $($enum_variants:ty),* ) => {
        match $input_str {
            $(
                stringify!($enum_variants) => {
                    let foo: $enum_variants = serde_json::from_value($action_args).unwrap();
                    foo.into()
                },
            )*
        }
    };
}


so that in the end I could just do:
let action: ActionEnum = match_all_variants!("MyAction2", my_args, ActionEnum, <something>);

action.run();

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve that? Ideally I didn't want to have to use a macro but I think there's no way without it.

Since you already use serde_json for deserialisation, I would let the deserialisation take care of the instantiation of the expected structure.
Please find below an attempt to adapt your example with this idea in mind.
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[enum_dispatch]
pub trait ActionRunner {
    fn run(&self);
}

#[enum_dispatch(ActionRunner)]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum ActionsEnum {
    MyAction(MyAction),
    MyAction2(MyAction2),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MyAction {
    a: i32,
    b: f32,
}

impl ActionRunner for MyAction {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("• running MyAction: a={} b={}", self.a, self.b);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MyAction2 {
    t: String,
}

impl ActionRunner for MyAction2 {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("• running MyAction2: t={:?}", self.t);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let incoming = [
        ("MyAction", r#"{"a": 123, "b": 45.67}"#),
        ("MyAction2", r#"{"t": "hello"}"#),
    ];
    for (action_name, args) in incoming {
        let full_json = format!("{{{:?}: {}}}", action_name, args);
        match serde_json::from_str::<ActionsEnum>(&full_json) {
            Ok(action) => {
                println!("Action: {:?}", action);
                action.run();
            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("cannot build action: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
/*
Action: MyAction(MyAction { a: 123, b: 45.67 })
• running MyAction: a=123 b=45.67
Action: MyAction2(MyAction2 { t: "hello" })
• running MyAction2: t="hello"
*/

